# Does Freemarker allow changes in existing files?

Tags: android-studio, freemarker

Can we update or change a file using Freemarker?
I am using Android studio templates to create few and I also want to update few files as well. Is it possible to do so? I am new to this and unable to find enough info.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker is a template engine to generate text output. What you can do is replace an existing file, with a new one.

Comment: No i would like to keep the existing one and based on supposedly some text, would like to change the value.

Comment: Freemarker is a template engine that's what it supposed to do is to change values in a text